# How to write to STD / docker logs from the wordpress docker image in PHP?

Tags: docker

if I use `error_log('hello');` it writes to `/proc/1/fd/2`, but how do I get `/proc/1/fd/2` to output to STD / docker logs?

my code:

```
add_action('init', function () {
  error_log('hello');
})
```

my docker compose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: user
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker logs shows the command’s STDOUT and STDERR by default. So, try something like:

```
file_put_contents('php://stderr', 'Your text goes to STDERR',FILE_APPEND);
```

source:

- [docker logging](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/)
- [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)